# Quarkus Websockets Virtual Threads

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, quarkus, jakarta-websockets

I followed this tutorial: https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets while trying to use virtual threads.

My initial assumption was that I could use the `@RunOnVirtualThread` annotation with the `@OnOpen` of jakarta.websocket so that I could simply call my repository like this:

```java
client.preparedQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $1")
      .execute(Tuple.of(id))
      .await().indefinitely();
```

After doing this I still get the error

```
Error on session null_null java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
```

Does this mean that Jakarta (or Quarkus) Websockets don't support virtual threads?

Comment: We don't yet have support for Virtual Threads in WebSockets. Feel free to ask for this feature on our Github issue tracker?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Will do.